# Why doesn't find_package() look in ${<name>_DIR}/lib/cmake/<name>-<version>?

Tags: cmake

I'm using cmake on Windows to build RTK which depends on ITK, but RTK (which uses find_package()) fails to find my ITK installation, although I provide its install location with `ITK_DIR`.

I have build ITK separately and installed it (using the cmake install target) in `<...>/ITK/install`. I can see that `ITKConfig.cmake` has been put in `<...>/ITK/install/lib/cmake/ITK-4.13`. I call cmake with

```
> cmake -DITK_DIR=<...>/ITK/install .
```

According to the [documentation of find_package()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/find_package.html):

> [...] CMake constructs a set of possible installation prefixes for the package. Under each prefix several directories are searched for a configuration file. The tables below show the directories searched. Each entry is meant for installation trees following Windows (W), UNIX (U), or Apple (A) conventions:
>
> ```
> <prefix>/                                                       (W)
> <prefix>/(cmake|CMake)/                                         (W)
> <prefix>/<name>*/                                               (W)
> <prefix>/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/                                 (W)
> <prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/cmake/<name>*/                  (U)
> <prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/<name>*/                        (U)
> <prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/          (U)
> <prefix>/<name>*/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/cmake/<name>*/          (W/U)
> <prefix>/<name>*/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/<name>*/                (W/U)
> <prefix>/<name>*/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/  (W/U)
> ```
>
> [...]
>   Directories above marked with (W) are intended for installations on Windows where the prefix may point at the top of an application’s installation directory. Those marked with (U) are intended for installations on UNIX platforms where the prefix is shared by multiple packages. **This is merely a convention, so all (W) and (U) directories are still searched on all platforms.**

Based on this information, I would expect find_package() to find `ITKConfig.cmake`. But it falls back to a system installation of ITK that I have in `C:\Program Files`. I enabled `CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE=ON` and got the following output from find_package():

```
  Checking file [C:/<...>/ITK/install/ITKConfig.cmake]
  Checking file [C:/<...>/ITK/install/itk-config.cmake]
  Checking prefix [C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/]
  Checking file [C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/ITKConfig.cmake]
  Checking file [C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/itk-config.cmake]
... <more> ...
```

It appears to look in `ITK_DIR`, but not in the subdirectory `lib/cmake/ITK-4.13`, where the `ITKConfig.cmake` file is.

If I, however, instead point out the particular folder in which this file is, like this:

```
> cmake -DITK_DIR=<...>/ITK/install/lib/cmake/ITK-4.13 .
```

then find_package() finds ITK and it works.

What do I misunderstand? I would prefer not to have to provide the version name of the package in the `ITK_DIR` variable, so the behavior described in the documentation would be nice to have.

Comment: Note, that search directories wouldn't contain **versioned** component `ITK-4.13/`. Not sure why ITK project installs the config file into that subdirectory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CMake** variable `Foo_DIR` is **not a prefix** for search configuration file for `Foo` package. This is a directory where configuration file is *exactly* located or not located at all:

> If `<PackageName>_DIR` has been set to a directory not containing a configuration file CMake will ignore it and search from scratch.

Description of the `find_package` contains algorithm for choose **prefixes**. One of them is:

> 3. Search paths specified in cmake-specific environment variables. ...
>
>    `<PackageName>_DIR`
>
>    CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
>
>    CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH
>
>    CMAKE_APPBUNDLE_PATH

Here you may find `<PackageName>_DIR` variable, but that time it is **environment** variable:

```
> ITK_DIR=<...>/ITK/install cmake .
```

If you want to set CMake variable, then you may set `<PackageName>_ROOT` variable:

```
> cmake -DITK_ROOT=<...>/ITK/install .
```

Note, that such variable is used only by the recent CMake versions (since CMake 3.12).